# It the phrase "They identify themselves as Pacifist, but the EU as an arrogant power" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjunctions

Is this phrase grammatical?

> They identify themselves as Pacifist, but the EU as an arrogant power.

Is a verb necessary in the second part of the sentence?

Comment: If there is anything in particular about the sentence you think is ungrammatical, you should edit the question to specify exactly what it is. Otherwise, this question asks for simple proofreading, which is [out of scope for this site](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and it will probably be closed as off-topic.

Comment: This is a case of zeugma (see Wikipedia), which is perfectly fine and correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "There is no need a verb in the second part". Please could you clarify?

Comment: Conjunction reduction has deleted the second occurrence of _they identify_ in the second clause. It's grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of confusing, and I think it could use a rewrite, but it's grammatically correct. It means the same things as

> They identify themselves as Pacifist, but they identify the EU as an arrogant power.

Answer (score -1):

"They identify themselves as Pacifist, but the EU as a arrogant power" Could be changed into "They identify themselves as Pacifist, but the EU as an arrogant power" because you have to have an before a word starting with a, other than that it sound good, but you could add in "was identified" so it would look like "They identify themselves as Pacifist, but the EU was identified as an arrogant power" so that there is no confusion in your sentence

Comment: The question is really asking about the need for a verb in the second clause.